# Как сверстать такой блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как можно сверстать блок с такой анимацией?
[Creativo Arquitectos Web Interactions](https://dribbble.com/shots/4836269-Creativo-Arquitectos-Web-Interactions)
(показала подруга-дизайнер, просто интересно).
Интересует, собственно, фон, а не надписи. Мне в голову не приходит ничего, кроме фонового gif или видео, ну или может можно как-то через svg исхитриться.

Comment: Посмотрите фильтры в css

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin Фильтры такого не сделают)

Comment: А что если сделать три картинки, формата png и через css накидывать фильтр "hue-rotate".

Comment: Самая простая реализация - использование слайдера с тремя разными по цветам картинками и таким же эффектом.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд тут три разных изображения, смена между ними происходит через css свойства mask, где сама маска задается анимированным svg файлом.

Answer (score 0):

На этом сайте используется фоновый .gif, я считаю, что вам в голову приходят здравые мысли (о фоновых .gif или видео)
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Это пустой блок с фоном из этой анимации: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/418188/screenshots/4836269/creativo_arquitectos_web_interactions.gif 
так что тут нечего и верстать.